# Are MYSQL connections containers for databases?

Tags: mysql

I am very new to mysql. I hope my question makes sense.

[image]
[image]

So I have two connections I created on MySQL workbench, one is called maji_ndogo (with a database called md_water_services) and the second one is crash_course(with two databases called land and feedback).

When I first created the  crash_course connection, it was showing the md_water_service database. I thought it was a default setting(to show databases from other connections) so I dropped the md_water_service database.

I went back to the maji_ndogo connection to see that it had also been dropped there. Additionally, the databases I created in my crash course connection (land and feedback) were also present here.

Firstly, have I been understanding connections in MySQL wrongly? I thought they were like containers for whatever databases you want to work on. I did not expect that databases I worked on in other connections would appear in the one I am working on, not to even say that they could be dropped from another connection

Secondly, is there a way for me to recover the maji ndogo database I mistakenly dropped?

Lastly, when I create a new connection, I don't want databases from other connections to be there. Is there a way for me to do this?

I would appreciate a reply to each of my questions. Thank you.

The first picture shows the maji_ndogo connection, it has the same databases as crash course connection.

I was expecting that I wouldn't see other databases in other connections.
When I dropped the maji ndogo database in the crash course connection, I wasn't expecting it to be dropped in its original connection , md_water_service.

Comment: A connection is just a connection. You are connected to the database server. You will see any databases your user has access to there. It's not an isolated container for that database. You would need to restore the dropped database from a backup.

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly, have I been understanding connections in MySQL wrongly? I thought they were like containers for whatever databases you want to work on. I did not expect that databases I worked on in other connections would appear in the one I am working on, not to even say that they could be dropped from another connection

Yes, you have the wrong understanding.

Think of it more like a filesystem on a remote host. Several users can use `ftp` to connect to that host and list the files on it (or if you prefer to think about Windows shared volumes, multiple users can map the network share).

Then a user in one `ftp` session can create a file or folder, and the other user immediately sees that file or folder, and if they have permissions to do so, they can delete it.

> Secondly, is there a way for me to recover the maji ndogo database I mistakenly dropped?

No, not unless you had created a [backup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-and-recovery.html).

> Lastly, When I create a new connection, I don't want databases from other connections to be there. Is there a way for me to do this?

You can manage this with [SQL privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/access-control.html). Users can only see schemas they have privilege to access.

It's common that users are granted SQL privileges with wildcards, like `GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO user@hostname`. In that case, they automatically get access to any new schemas and tables. You can prevent this simply by not issuing grants with wildcards to any users on your server. Only grant access to specific schemas.